# Can water-based wood glue deep in timber joinery initiate wood rot?

Tags: wood, woodworking, adhesive

In joinery projects where PVA glue is restricted access to air (for example, with doweling) moisture is dissipated through the surrounding wood and the glue typically takes longer to dry.

Is there risk of wood rot in the surrounding timber in situations like this, or with excessive glue use?

Comment: iirc, most airborne fungi need air to grow, which would be in short supply internally. you could pre-treat with boric acid to prevent mold.

Comment: I don't know if this counts as an answer or just speculation, but I would expect the moisture would be well dissipated much more quickly than any biological life could take hold.

Answer (score 3):

Water based glue quickly drys out and has been used for centuries. If it created rot we would have no antiques as most very old joinery is held together by tight joints and glue only. Two much glue wipe the excess but it will dry if their is an internal puddle and won’t cause rot.